# Java Print Value Object on Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I set list on another class

```
List<DataModel> dataList = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
```

parsed on class

```
for(DataModel list : dataList) {
    final String[] data = {list.getVar_a(), list.getVar_b()};
    System.out.println("out data");
    System.out.println(list.getVar_a());
    System.out.println(list.getVar_b());
}
```

this prints data

```
out data
val_a
val_b
```

Model Class

```
class DataModel {
    private String var_a, var_b;

    //Getter & Setter
}
```

But now, I use and set map on another class and I'm not implementing a model class because in real case it has too many variables.

```
Map<String, Object> mapData = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

when I set data on map, its result from database

```
Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
msg = (String) cs.getObject(5);
rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(4);

ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int count = rsmd.getColumnCount();
if(rs.next()){
    int jml = 0;
    do {
        Map<String, Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++ ) {
            String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            data.put(name, rs.getObject(name));
            
        }
        map.put(""+jml, data);
        jml++;
    } while(rs.next());
    
    setStatus(SUCCESS);
    setMessage(msg);
} else {
    LOG.info(NO_DATA_FOUND);
}
```

parsed on class

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Object> list : mapData.entrySet()) {
    String key = list.getKey();
    Object val = list.getValue();
    System.out.println("out data");
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

this prints data

```
out data
0
{var_a=val_a, var_b=val_b}
```

I want to get value on object like this

```
out data
val_a
val_b
```

Comment: You need to show how the map is being constructed and  your `DataModel` class  And in the `parsed on class` section, why are you putting the values in an array but printing them with their getters?

Comment: `{var_a=val_a, var_b=val_b}` looks like the EntrySet of another map.  To provide an accurate answer, more information is required.

Comment: @WJS sure, i edit my question.

Comment: Thanks!.  At this point I recommend you put in print statements to verify what the data looks like.  I would print `rsmd.getColumnName(i)` and `rs.getObject(name)`. since those are what you are putting in the map.  Printing other values may be beneficial too.  It wouldn't surprise me if `name = "0"` But then, it's a guess at this point.

Comment: i put this code `System.out.println(name+"|"+rs.getObject(name));` in loop entryset map.
result:
`col_a|col_a
col_b|col_b
...|...
col_z|col_z`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First you have a map of object, and what you really need is a Map of Map.

Here is your reading a map of object.

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Object> list : mapData.entrySet()) {
    String key = list.getKey();
    Object val = list.getValue();
    System.out.println("out data");
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

What you really need is a map of map as I am showing below.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>()
```

Now if you read it as map of map, You can have the result that you need.

`0` : {a1:v1, a2:v2, etc...},
`1` : {a2:v2, a2:v2, etc...},
`2` : {a3:v3, a3:v3, etc...}

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Map<String, Object> list : mapData.entrySet()) {
    String key = list.getKey();
    System.out.println("out data");
    for(Map.Entry<String,Object> innermap : list.getValue().entrySet()) {
        //System.out.println(innermap.getKey());
        System.out.println(innermap.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a speculation on what the OP's code did.

Comment: There is not enough information to help the OP.  That is why I asked the questions in the comments.  Otherwise, everyone is guessing.

Comment: I agree, but the point is here is to active his output. And it active his output. As i said we can do alot of thing to improve the code make it short, clear, etc.. But maybe he is a new developer and it could be more confuse to him.

Comment: You said about "speculation", there is not speculaiton. After he tried to use `map`. He said at the end `i want to get value on object like this` > `out data
val_a
val_b`. He wants the same output that he got before.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the real case i dont want use model class, cause in real case its have many variable.

Comment: @BudiSantoso I changed the answer, i hope it fix your problem

Answer (score -1):

Change your Map for loop to:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Object> list : mapData.entrySet()) {
        DataModel value = (DataModel) list.getValue();
        System.out.println("out data");
        System.out.println(value.getVar_a());
        System.out.println(value.getVar_b());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the real case i dont want use model class, cause in real case its have many variable.